# Data frame transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I am very novice Python pandas user so this may be a dumb question and pandas may have simple method to do this operation

My data frame is as follows:

```
Name        Activity      Date
Abc.           Run.           June 3
Cde.           Walk.         Sept. 4
Abc.           Run.           June 4
Abc.           Run.           June 5
Code.         Walk.          June 3
Cde.            Run.           Sept 5
```

I want to convert it to

```
Name  run freq  walk freq 
Abc.       3.             0
Cde.        1.             1
Code.      0.            1
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Comment: What is the output of this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group on the column, get the count of each, and then unstack the results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Abc.', 'Cde.', 'Abc.', 'Abc.', 'Code.', 'Cde.'], 
                   'Activity': ['Run.', 'Walk.', 'Run.', 'Run.', 'Walk.', 'Run.'], 
                   'Date': ['June 3', 'Sept. 4', 'June 4', 'June 5', 'June 3', 'Sept 5']})

>>> df.groupby(['Name', 'Activity']).count().unstack()

          Date       
Activity  Run.  Walk.
Name                 
Abc.         3    NaN
Cde.         1      1
Code.      NaN      1
```

Comment: I am seeing different behaviour if I only have two columns  - name and activity. with two columns, I am not getting count but empty cells. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you counting?  If your df only has Name and Activity, and you use both of those to group, then what would you like to count?

Comment: I want to count the number of time, any name has done an activity. For the example above, Abc ran 3 times and no walk.

Comment: `df[['Name', 'Activity']].groupby(['Name', 'Activity']).Name.count().unstack()`

Comment: Trying this but my column name in the actual data set as Name as 'Name Of', when I try to substitute "Name" with "Name Of" I get error.

Comment: `df[['Name Of', 'Activity']].groupby(['Name Of', 'Activity'])["Name Of"].count().unstack()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98384/discussion-between-1974sb-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by name and activity and get the sum:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Activity']).sum()
```